# How to handle the difference in Android 4.2.2 vs older versions for canvas.drawText

Tags: android, canvas

I use drawText to draw some text to a canvas. 
Before Android 4.2.2 the coordinate 0,0 was on top left and 0.5/0.5 was at the center of my canvas.
In Android 4.2.2 the when I draw to 0.5/0.5 the text is on the left rim of the canvas and 1.0/0.5 is at the center. So it's shifted 0.5 on the x-axis.

This is the code:

```
Canvas backgroundCanvas = new Canvas(background);
float scale = (float) getWidth();
backgroundCanvas.scale(scale, scale);
final int desityDPi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
float convertedTextSize = (float) valueTextSize / (float) desityDPi;

scalePaint.setTextSize(convertedTextSize);
scalePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

backgroundCanvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
backgroundCanvas.drawText("x", 0.5f, 0.5f, scalePaint);
backgroundCanvas.drawText("+", 1.0f, 0.5f, scalePaint);
```

so in Andriod < 4.2.2 the x is in the center of the canvas and in Android 4.2.2 the + is in the center.

I do not have any idea what is going on - this can't be normal I would assume.

Is there something wrong with the code or do I really have to write an if-statement distinguishing between the Android versions for the coordinates ?

Comment: Is it possible that you run it on a different density than the one you used before? maybe it's a rounding issue. Can you please post an image of "before" and "after" ?

Comment: no, I don't think its a rounding issue. This issue is consitent to all users with Android 4.2.2 and there are quite many. Also I tried it in the simulator just changing the Androi version - that really causes this. My canvas is about 7cm, and the x and + are really 50% apart just depending on Android version

Comment: Can you please show an image of before and after? maybe by looking at it we can see what could be the problem. also, other relevant code can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've proven that there truly is a difference in the code due to the API then just use API specific code, but I suspect there's another issue:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
    // Do something for 4.2 and above
} else{
    // Do something different for older versions
}
```